# Cannot open the reference vector file. What is it?

Tags: c, vb.net, vector, command-line

I am trying to execute a .exe file (created in C), from VB code shell function. The same code can open notepad.exe without any problem. But when I am trying to start my program made in C, it gives a msg "cannot open the reference vector file."

then after pressing any key, it is showing the "Program has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience." error report. Then it closes.

Searching the term "cannot open the reference vector file" gives no result. Kindly help me.

Note: "cannot open the reference vector file" error is being given in command prompt. Not from VB. Even when I start that exe from command line, same thing happpens. But by double click, the file runs perfect.

Comment: What does your program do? What does the VB code do?

Comment: in command prompt are you executing the binary at correct path???

Comment: How are you starting the C program from your VB.NET code (and the command prompt, since that also fails)?  Are you setting the working directory appropriately?

Comment: The C program is an OCR. It is created by others and they will not give me the source code.

Comment: Presently it proceses all the images in a particullar folder and output the text files in another folder. But it can not process more than 12 image files, it just crashes. I am using VB for copying one image to that folder, then process it, then exit the programm. Then copy another and loop through this.

LOOP
1. Browse a folder where the images reside.
2. copy one image into the processable folder.
3. Run the exe from shell () and extract the text.
4. close the exe
5. empty the processable folder.
LOOP END

Comment: For starting command line, just using C:\ocr.exe or start C:\ocr.exe

Answer (score 0):

The C program is an OCR. It is created by others and they will not give me the source code. Presently it proceses all the images in a particullar folder and output the text files in another folder. But it can not process more than 12 image files, it just crashes. I am using VB for copying one image to that folder, then process it, then exit the programm. Then copy another and loop through this.

1. Browse a folder where the images reside.
2. copy one image into the processable folder.
3. Run the exe from shell () and extract the text.
4. close the exe
5. empty the processable folder.
   LOOP it